# SQL query to ignore record

Tags: sql, db2

I have table with column 1 same for client and column 2 has different value , if I find a column 2 with a value then all the records for the client should not show in my results

Column 1    Column2

123. 1
124. 2
125. 3

In the above if I use where column2=1 then I should not have all the records

Basically I want to skip 123 if column 2 has 1

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Column1 <> '123' AND Column2 = 1`

#### UPDATED with Join Condition

`SELECT your_table.* FROM your_table 
 INNER JOIN clients ON your_table.Column1 = clients.NAME
 WHERE your_table.Column2 = 1
 AND clients.NAME <> 'abc'`

Comment: If I have 2 tables one is above and another one table 2 is with only distinct of column 1, so here column 1 from table 2 and check for the condition in table2.column 2 and show all records matches the condition

Comment: answer updated according to your comments @Christopher Lewis

Comment: Thanks , I want the whole join records. I will not provide the clients name in where condition

Comment: Could you update you question with more specific table schema model and the result you wanted?